# Collecting items inside parentheses

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have an expression of this type:
$$\left( 1+\frac{a+b}{c}\right)^{d} $$
My question is, how can I collect variables inside parentheses? Of course without putting commands inside parentheses.

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking. Could you show what would you like the output to look like for the above expression after "collecting" the variables as you say?

Comment: $$\left(\frac{c+a+b}{c}\right)^{d}$$

Comment: Just do `Simplify[expr]` here is screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pFgXm.png)

Comment: Indeed, feel myself dumb, but why it does not work for $(1+\frac{1}{x})^{d}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why it does not work for (1+1/x)^d

Because `Simplify` does not see `((1+x)/x)^d)` as simpler.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

If you always have the form `(stuff)^d`, then you can try this, which worked for both examples

```
Clear["Global`*"];
expr = (1 + (a + b)/c)^d;
Together[First@expr]^d
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
expr = (1 + 1/x)^d;
Together[First@expr]^d
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
expr = (1 + (a + b + e + f)/c + 3/h)^d;
Together[First@expr]^d
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You could automate this more if needed, so that exponent `d` do not have to be explicit as shown above.